# How to Set up LDAP integration for Content Manager?

Tags: web8, installation, ldap

I have installed SDL Web 8 in one of the servers and currently I am trying to configure LDAP through directory services.
As per documentation we need to "Collect LDAP server data"
I have collected the following information from existing server using LDP tool.

1. subschemaSubentry:
2. dsServiceName:;
3. namingContexts:
4. defaultNamingContext:;
5. schemaNamingContext:;
6. configurationNamingContext:;
7. rootDomainNamingContext:
8. supportedControl:
9. supportedLDAPVersion:
10. supportedLDAPPolicies:
11. highestCommittedUSN:;
12. supportedSASLMechanisms:;
13. dnsHostName:;
14. ldapServiceName:;
15. serverName:;
16. supportedCapabilities:
17. isSynchronized: TRUE;
18. isGlobalCatalogReady: TRUE;
19. domainFunctionality: 6;
20. forestFunctionality: 6;
21. domainControllerFunctionality: 6;

Where as I was unable to get the below data

1. Search Account DN
2. Username attribute
3. User Description attribute
4. User Description attribute
5. Users base DN
6. Groups base DN

Can you please guide me to fetch the details from existing server so that I can configure them same in new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can remember:

- Search Account DN

The account that the CM should use when logging in to LDAP to validate users

- Username attribute

What is the name of the attribute in your LDAP under which the username is stored?

- User Description attribute

What is the name of the attribute in your LDAP under which the user description is stored?

- Users base DN

Where in your LDAP tree should we search for users?

- Groups base DN

Where in your LDAP tree should we search for groups?